# Facebook status manager

Tags: facebook

I can't find the status manager (or subscription manager?) on Facebook. I know I can unsubscribe from status updates on the News Feed, but it is very slow.

Anyone knows where is this status manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to selectively bulk unsubscribe from status updates ("Hide Story").

When you hide a story the following notice appears

[image: Hiding a story from the App Store]

Then if you hide all posts from the user/page in question will no longer appear in your News Feed.

You can however use the Subscriptions page to change your subscriptions of users and friends

> http://facebook.com/profile.php?sk=subscribedto

Where yourusername is the username to link to your profile.

And your friend subscriptions are at

> http://facebook.com/profile.php?sk=subscribedto&filter=1

You can reach these links also via your profile (under your cover photo)

[image: Link on the far right goes to the subscriptions and other pages]

[image: Subscriptions Shown]

Comment: facebook.com/yourusername/subscribedto --> this is exactly what I searched, thanks a lot! It is well hidden...